# Updating/Refreshing combobox in C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, combobox, refresh

We are creating a project in C#. We are reading data from our database (Microsoft Access) and show it in a combobox. Then we put new data in the database. Now the combobox has to update to display the new edited data. How can we update this combobox?

Thanks!

Comment: It is your program that adds new data or it is an external source/event?

Comment: It's our program that adds new data into the database.

Comment: WPF or WinForms? (Or, to put it another way: what is the fully qualified, namespace included, name of the combo box control?)

Comment: If it is your program then you have a starting point to work with. In that point reload your combo data. To answer correctly you need to show the code that fills the combo and the code that change/update the data.

Comment: I'm sorry but we are new to C# and we don't really know what you mean with the name of the combobox control, the name of our combobox is 'combobox1' and the datasource is 'RichtingEnJaarBindingSource' and the DisplayMember is 'Naam'.

Comment: This is the code that fills the combobox when loading the form: this.richtingEnJaarTableAdapter.Fill(this.projectDataSet.RichtingEnJaar);
            this.klassenTableAdapter.Fill(this.projectDataSet.Klassen);

Answer (score -1):

The code you are looking for is:

```
YourComboxBoxName.Refresh();
```

Comment: Refresh has nothing to do with the data contained in the combo. Very bad answer indeed